# Forbid access to REST webservices

Tags: php, api, http, security

I am trying to find the best, reliadble and secure practice in order to fordid or restrict access to my API php webservices which are called from browser bar or some API client but allow access when request comes form my website.

I though that maybe i could use custom `$_SESSION` variables to set access_key on domain load so on each API call to check if access_key exists or not.

Is this an acceptable and secure way?

Comment: Many APIs require a valid token is sent as part of the request. Without the token or an incorrect token there is no access

Comment: Sure. But in `ajax` requests I want to avoid someone getting the token and use it.

Comment: you only mentioned `allow access when request comes form my website` - no mention of ajax

Comment: You mean to use this header - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?